# How to populate a Backbone.js collection's _byId array so that I can use `get` on it?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection, and the `collection.models` returns an array of models. However, when I call `collection.get(someId)` (and this id is the id of the model that is in the `collection.models` array), I get `undefined`. Looking at `collection._byId`, it looks like an empty object.

How do I properly populate `_byId`, so that I can use `get`? Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong when initializing my collection, which is why `_byId` is empty.

Comment: How are you initializing your collection?

Comment: I followed the [thoughtbot book](http://ui.thoughtbot.com/assets/backbone-js-on-rails-thoughtbot-ebook-august-2011-sample.html) for the initialization part. I'm using json like [this](https://gist.github.com/2325408) (trimmed most of the attributes to be concise). I pass that into the controller class when creating it: `controller = new MyController(jsonYouSeeAbove)`. Perhaps the JSON is wrong?

Comment: I see my problem. The `to_json` method I used doesn't return the right json sequence. I should return an array of hashes like the value of "model" in the hash in the gist.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late, but hopefully this is still useful to some other people.

Collection._byId is just a normal js hash object.  There's really nothing fancy about it.  If you want Collection.get to work, just add all the models into the _byId hash.

Inside the collection's scope:

```
var someId = '123'; // any id will do

this._byId[someId] = someModel; // someModel.id = '123'

console.log(!!this.get(someId)); // should return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using this with Rails, the default json generated by Rails doesn't work well with Backbone. I don't know why I didn't see it while trying to learn Backbone. Anyway, you could either:

1. Change the way Rails generates its JSON
2. [Change the way your Backbone app reads the JSON](https://gist.github.com/719080).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the OP had a slightly different problem, but I experienced a similar issue and thought I'd post what worked for me.

Like the original issue, `collection.models` contained the right model, but in my case, the `_byId` hash contained a [`cid`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) version of the model that wasn't empty. Nevertheless, `_byId` didn't contain a model with normal id (there's usually two version - an `id` one and a `cid` one), so I wasn't able to use `collection.get(id)` to retrieve it. My problem became a bit clearer when I read up about `cid`. From the docs:

> Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to the server, and does not yet have its eventual true id, but already needs to be visible in the UI.

I didn't think it was a problem with waiting for the server as my `cid` model and the `collection.model` had the correct ids. However passing in `{ wait : true }` as an option in `collection.create` fixed this issue for me.