# Backbone Collection model IDs not being saved in _byId

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone app working with Rails. There is a collection of lists that I'm fetching from my API in rails. The JSON for each model in the collection looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "4ffc55680be4443f66000005",
  "created_at": "2012-07-10T09:16:40-07:00",
  "name": "List-1",
  "list_items": []
}
```

For some reason, when I fetch the collection, the _byId object of the lists collection is not being populated. Is my JSON formatted incorrectly or is there another issue here?

Comment: Are you doing `c.fetch(); console.log(c)` or similar? The real question I suppose is "how do you know the collection looks like that but `_byId` isn't right?"

Comment: "How do you know the collection looks like that" - This is the JSON that is returned when directly hitting /api/v1/lists (the same url that the collection is getting lists from)

"Are you doing c.fetch(): console.log(c)" - I'm doing the log in the fetch success function to make sure that the collection has been returned when the log gets made.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess probably is right.
It's the way Rails generates the JSON.

You can change Rails, or change the way Backbone reads the JSON
https://gist.github.com/719080

Credit: [How to populate a Backbone.js collection's _byId array so that I can use `get` on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051471/how-to-populate-a-backbone-js-collections-byid-array-so-that-i-can-use-get-o)